# Multi-monitor support?

Tags: vmware, usability, multiple-monitors, vmware-workstation

My PC has 4 monitors and I'd like to use 2 of them on VMware Workstation, so that its displays be maximized. But it seems that it doesn't support using more than 1 display. At least it doesn't have option to add new display, and I didn't find it on its docs.

Unity isn't an option, because my main use case would be having Win10 as host and Linux with Gnome as guest, and I wanna use Gnome features because it has productivity than Windows. So it wouldn't work to bring Linux windows to Win10.

Answer (score 0):

Should be available as a settings in: VM Settings > Hardware > Display

You can either set the VM to default to whatever the host system is using or to a specific amount.

Here's the docs for it: [Configure Monitor for VM with Workstation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-FF434E5C-2FEE-48C9-BEAF-943F0536301E.html#GUID-FF434E5C-2FEE-48C9-BEAF-943F0536301E)